# Trigger plugin on creation of a new entiy

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I need to write a plugin for Dynamics CRM 2016 and the plugin needs to be triggered on creation of a new entity, not an entity record but a new entity. For example if I import a new solution and that solution contains few custom entities then I need to be able to be able to trigger the plugin when the new custom entities are created. Is it possible?

Comment: Is the CRM on-prem or online ?

Comment: I wanted to know in both scenarios but mainly for Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't handle with plugins such operations.

Comment: Thanks Adrii, I did some more research and doesn't look like it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research found that it is not possible. Here is a list of all supported messages for plugins and it doesn't look like you can trigger a plugin on creation of a custom entity (entity itself, not the entity record):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx